# How do you display information in multiple columns programmatically in a web part?

Tags: web-part, list-view, column, gridview

I am developing a web part (not a visual web part) that displays the site owners of a SharePoint site and their email addresses. Right now I am displaying the information in a listbox. It displays the site owners and emails like this:

```
Smith, John - Smith_John@xxx.com

Washington, Anna - Washington_Anna@xxx.com
```

This is the code I have:

```
public class SiteOwners : WebPart
{

    string mySiteURL = "my SharePoint URL goes here";
    ListBox mySPLists = new ListBox();
    string listInfo = "";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(mySPLists);

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mySiteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPGroup ownerGroup = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
                if (ownerGroup != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPUser user in ownerGroup.Users)
                    {
                            listInfo = user.Name + " - " + user.Email;
                            mySPLists.Items.Add(listInfo);
                    }
                }
                //web.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display the site owners' names and emails in 2 different columns so that it looks better. I want it to look like this:

```
Site Owner              Email

Smith, John             Smith_John@xxx.com

Washington, Anna        Washington_Anna@xxx.com
```

Should I use a list view, data grid, table? Advice on how to use these items would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Populate a data table with the necessary values and bind it the SPGridView. You can use below code to start with:

```
 public class SiteOwners : WebPart
    {

        string mySiteURL = "my SharePoint URL goes here";
                string listInfo = "";
    SPGridView spGrid=new SPGridView();
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

            DataTable dtTable=new DataTable();
            dtTable.Columns.Add("Name");
            dtTable.Columns.Add("Email");

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mySiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPGroup ownerGroup = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
                    if (ownerGroup != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SPUser user in ownerGroup.Users)
                        {
                                DataRow dtRow=dtTable.NewRow();
                                dtRow["Name"]=user.Name;
                                dtRow["Email"]=user.Email;
                               dtTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                        }
                    }
                   spGrid.DataSource =dtTable;
                   spGrid.DataBind();
                }

            }
            this.Controls.Add(spGrid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mischa you will have to add System.Data.dll reference in your solution and add using System.Data in your code

Comment: I get an error that says: "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.


This derived class does not allow AutoGenerateColumns to be true. You must specify each of the columns using BoundField, TemplateField, or other compatible class." 

I added the line "spGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;" and the error goes away, but nothing is displaying when I run the web part.

Comment: It works now! I added the line dtTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);